# Key Up isn't working Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, keyup

I have no idea how this works. I am trying to learn key events. I got keydown to work, but key up just won't work. Any help appreciated.

```
      window.onload = function(){

        window.addEventListener('keyup' , loopit1 ); // this doesn't work.
        /*window.addEventListener('keydown' , loopit2 );*/ // this works. That's why it's commented out.

        function loopit1(e){
        if(e.ctrlKey){
        alert("Key Up!");
        }
        //This doesn't work.
        }

        /*function loopit2(e){
        if(e.ctrlKey){
        alert("Key Down!");
        }
        }*// This Works. That's why it's commented out.

}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Made one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ApZx5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you log out the event object, you'll see that `e.ctrlKey = true` on the `keydown` event, but `e.ctrlKey = false` on the `keyup` event.

**Why you ask?**

I can't really refer you to a source or any facts, but my thesis is like this:

The `e.ctrlKey`  property is there for you to check if the ctrl key is pressed down while you click a button. As you'll find out by checking it out, the event object has a lot of these properties for you to check. This way, it's easier to check if the user is clicking ctrl+s or alt+f7 or whatever.

The reason the e.ctrlKey always is false is probably because is never needed. Weird perhaps, but it doesn't really make sense to have it set in the first place, given my argument above.

A solution to your problem is to check the keyCode property instead - the key for ctrl is 17.

```
function loopit1(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 17){
        alert("Key Up!");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: WHOA! That's so crazy. Tried it, it actually works. Thank you, I shall now declare you today's javascript hero! Take care. :)

Comment: WHOA indeed. Please mark as correct answer if this helped you, so that it can help more people that have the same problem in the future =)

Answer (score 2):

It does work. The `ctrlKey` property indicates whether the `Ctrl` key is pressed at the time that the event fires. Therefore, it won't fire if the `Ctrl` key was the key that just came up, since the `keyup` event fires temporally after the `Ctrl` key comes up. If the `Ctrl` key is down while *another* key comes up, then `e.ctrlKey` will be true.

However, it needs to be a key that doesn't cause a browser action that takes away focus from the document -- if I bring the `T` key up while holding down `Ctrl`, the browser will move to a new tab before the event can happen. Try out `Ctrl+Alt`: while holding down the `Ctrl` key, press and release `Alt`.

If you want to test whether the `Ctrl` key itself has been lifted, you should check `e.keyCode` for the value `17`. However, [`e.keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), and should be replaced with `e.key` in the future. *However,* `e.key` is not yet widely implemented, so you *must* use `keyCode` for the time being.

Comment: Very insightful detail on the depreciation bit. Thanks!